# Working with google API on an unstable network

Tags: java, network-programming, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have written a managment application which has a function to put a bunch of events in multiple Google calendars.

On my computer everything works fine. But the main user of this application has a verry bad network connection. More percicely the ping to different server varies between 23ms and like 2000 ms and packets get lost.

My approach was, besides increasing the timout, to use an own thread for each API call and recall in case of an connection error.

And at this point I got stuck. Now every event is created. Unfortunately not once but at least once. So some events were uploaded mutiple times.

I have already tried to group them as batch requests, but google doesn't want events on multiple calendars in a single batch request.

I hope my situtaion is clear and someone has a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to persuade the "main user" to get a better network connection.

If that is impossible, I would change the code to have the following logic:

```
  // Current version
  createEvent(parameters)

  // New version
  while (queryEvent(parameters) -> no event) {
      createEvent(parameters)
  }
```

with appropriate timeouts and retry counters.  The idea is to implement some extra logic to make the creation of an event in the calendar idempotent. (This may entail generating a unique identifier on the client side for each event so that you can query the events reliably.)